# 2 bytes to custom format floating point

Tags: c++, floating-point

I have an array of bytes with this specification:

```
byte[0]: upper 4 bits is the exponential part, the rest is significant (high)
byte[1]: significant low
Number of decimals is 2
Unit is in "m"
```

[full specification](https://eww.pass.panasonic.co.jp/pro-av/support/content/guide/EN/top.html) (P2Device Control > P2_Device_Control_Protocol_&_Command.pdf > page 111)

Some sample values:

```
 0xB3 0x70 should be 8,8mm (but units is in m so 0,0088m or 0m (only 2 decimals)
 0xC3 0xE9 should be 100mm (so 0,10m)
 0xC6 0xE0 should be 176mm (so 0,176m)
```

How do I convert this custom floating point data to a normal float in C++

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The specification lacks some details -- like does it have an implied '1' bit or not. Then you claim that `byte[1]` contains 2 decimals -- shouldn't the bottom nibble of `byte[0]` have the same format? And is there an implicit bias in the exponent? Is the exponent signed or not? Is the significant signed? Is there an implicit bias in the significant?
btw. 12 bits is enough for 3.5 decimals.

Comment: I don't think it's signed, the unit is meters and in the protocol it's used for a focal length. The number of decimals is about the whole number.

Comment: This is all the documentation (first part is an overlay of all the bytes and what they are for) [link](https://imgur.com/rcNoSP2)

Comment: The fraction portion of a floating-point number is the “significand,” not a “significant.” I would edit it to correct it except you show it in quoted text. Is the error in the original?

Comment: this error is also in the original documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the values provided and given exponent `k` and significand `s` the formula for the value seems to be

```
s * 10^(k-16)
```

(`^` being exponentiation here)

so you could implement the conversion as

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

constexpr float toExponent(unsigned char value)
{
    return value - 16;
}

float convert(unsigned char bytes[2])
{
    auto significand = ((static_cast<unsigned int>(bytes[0]) & 0b1111) << 8) | bytes[1];

    auto exponent = toExponent(bytes[0] >> 4);

    return std::powf(10, exponent) * significand;
}

//demonstrate conversions of provided values
int main()
{
    unsigned char val[2]{ 0xB3, 0x70};
    unsigned char val2[2]{ 0xC3, 0xE9 };
    unsigned char vals[][2]
    {
        {0xB3, 0x70}, // 0.0088
        {0xC3, 0xE9}, // 0.1
        {0xC6, 0xE0}, // 0.176
    };

    for (size_t i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << convert(vals[i]) << '\n';
    }
    

    return 0;
}
```

Note that as mentioned by @chtz in the comments the exponent could also be a the 4 bit integer using 2s complement representation which could result in different values, if the first bit of the exponent is 0. It would be preferrable, if you could get the conversion of a value for this case.

Comment: thanks a lot! I would never been able to figure that out!

Comment: From the examples it is not clear if the exponent is `value-16` or `(value ^ 8) - 8` (i.e., like a signed 4bit value)

Answer (score 0):

With the specification of [image]

(After getting the reference values, the exponent seems not to be in powers of two, but in (negative) powers of 10)

Then the corresponding integer value is

```
value = (byte[1] + (byte[0] & 15) * 256);
exponent = (byte[0] >> 4) - 16;
float_val = (float)value * pow(10.f, (float)exponent);
```

and that can be converted to floating point by casting, where byte must be a pointer to **unsigned** char.

Comment: Floating-point exponent encodings usually have a bias, which must be subtracted from the encoding to get the represented exponent. And that allows negative exponents, which makes a left-shift inadequate to adjust the significand.

Comment: Where does the image in the answer come from? The question does not cite a source.

Comment: True, but as this is the only document, an alternative to bias is an implicit _unit_, such as mm.

Comment: changed it in the original post, looking too much to the programming side and not to the common sense :)